# how to safely distinguish ISO 8601 string and number stored as string in queryParams without regex

Tags: javascript, lodash, query-string

I have for example a date and amount property stored in the url als query params

> ...?date=2019-06-12T06:20:39.465Z&amount=20000

I want to be able to parse ALL query params and assign them to their proper type with javascript.

currently I'm using

```
        paramMap.keys.forEach(key => {
            let value: any = paramMap.get(key);
            if (isFinite(Date.parse(value))) {
                // keep as string
            } else if (isFinite(parseInt(value, 10))) {
                value = isInteger(value) ? parseInt(value, 10) : parseFloat(value);
            } else if (value === 'true' || value === 'false') {
                value = value === 'true';
            }
            obj[key] = value;
        });
        return obj;
```

In this case the amount=20000 will get recognised by Date.parse.

also

2019-06-12T06:20:39.465Z will be parsed to 2019 with parseInt...

isFinie, parseInt and isInteger are imported from lodash.

If possible I dont want to use regex.

EDIT: Please assume that I don't know the name of the key. Hence the script should work for all properties.

Comment: Would not make sense to check the parameter name? For example, if `key` equals `date`?

Comment: See the updated edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function, or lodash's [`_.toNumber()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toNumber) which will return `NaN` for strings with mixed numbers:

```js
console.log(+'2019-06-12T06:20:39.465Z')

console.log(+'20000')
```

So the logic would be:

```js
const parseParam = value => {
  let v = +value

  if (!isNaN(v)) return v

  v = Date.parse(value)

  if (!isNaN(v)) return v

  if (value === 'true' || value === 'false') return value === 'true'

  return value
}

console.log(parseParam('2019-06-12T06:20:39.465Z'))
console.log(parseParam('20000'))
console.log(parseParam('false'))
console.log(parseParam('cats'))
```

Answer (score 2):

ISO may omit seconds or timezone or milliseconds, but if you ignore those and check everything else you can reliably check against different ISO formats.

```js
console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39.234Z'))
console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39'))
console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20'))

console.log(isISO("2019-1-1"))
console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39+05'))

console.log(isISO('ketchup'))

function isISO(str) {
  try {
    str = str.split('+')[0];
    var iso = new Date(str).toISOString();
    var [date, time] = iso.split('T');
    var [y, m, d] = date.split('-');
    return iso.indexOf(`${y}-${m}-${d}`) === 0;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but that doesn't work if the input ISO 8601 date isn't "padded" (for lack of a better term). Check `console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39'))` or `console.log(isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39Z'))`, both valid ISO date AFAICT

Comment: you fixed `isISO("2019-1-1")` but broke `isISO('2019-06-12T06:20:39+05')` I think (and I want to say sorry I'm finding those bugs, but instead I'll congratulate you on your continued effort to fix them ;-) )

Comment: so trim it.. i added your examples.. they work fine.

Comment: Nice, can't think of anything else.